# How to enter nested element?

Tags: d3.js

I have six parent elements (6 times "div") and I'm appending three children, one for each of the last three parents.

```
d3.select("body").selectAll("div")
    .data(["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"])
    .enter().append("div")
    .attr("class", "parent")
    .text(function (d) {
    return d;
});

d3.selectAll("div")
    .filter(function (d, i) {
    return i > 2 ? true : false;
})
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "children")
    .text(function (d) {
    return "Name of child: " + d;
});
```

This results in the following output:

```
one
two
three
four
Name of child: four
five
Name of child: five
six
Name of child: six
```

Now, I want to update the children based on the data. The result should have children at three, four and five.

The problem is to append the entering child three at the right position in the DOM. E.g. The following try:

```
var newChildren = ["three", "four", "five"];

var updateSel = d3.selectAll(".children").data(newChildren, function (d) {
    return d;
});
updateSel.exit().remove();
updateSel.enter().append("div")
    .attr("class", "children")
    .text(function (d) {
    return "Name of child: " + d;
});
```

would enter child three at the wrong place since the parents are not specified as parent node.

```
one
two
three
four
Name of child: four
five
Name of child: five
six
Name of child: three
```

[Here's the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ee2todev/j8tj6n90/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `updateSel` needs to be based on the parent nodes, not the child nodes, since it's the parent nodes that you want to be potentially adding children to.

So your initial selection becomes:

```
var updateSel = d3.selectAll(".parent").data(newChildren, function (d) {
    return d;
});
```

Then your remove command will have to remove children instead of the nodes in the exit selection:

```
updateSel.exit().selectAll("*").remove();
```

Finally, your append command must be filtered to apply only to those nodes that don't already have children:

```
updateSel.filter(function() {
    return d3.select(this).select(".children").empty();
}).append("div")
    .attr("class", "children")
    .text(function (d) {
    return "Name of child: " + d;
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly! While you answered my question, consider the case, the data would be just bound to the 3 children (not to the parent nodes). It would be great if you could add to your answer how to deal with that ?

Comment: Hm... if data are not bound to the parents but only to the children, then on what basis would you be able to determine which parents need to have new children added to them?

Comment: You are right, my question is underspecified! In my application the parents have the same data in it, and as you say, for a good reason. I guess, why I was thinking this direction initially and now (on the wrong track) is that I thought my children get updated not the parents. But I can just implement the standard update on children if every parent has its children, so it's completely specified, in my case I have to consult the parents:) Thanks a lot, was really helpfull!